# new API key for Filecoin Lotus node

Tags: filecoin, filecoin-lotus

I'm trying to generate a new API-KEY for a Lotus node (existing one may have been compromised), but when I run `lotus auth create-token --perm read` it simply returns the existing key. The docs seem to suggest there is also an `authnew` command, but `lotus authnew create-token --perm read` throws an error "No help topic for 'authnew'". Does anyone know how to generate a new api key, assuming this is possible? Thanks so much for any assistance!

edit: it looks like `lotus auth create-token --perm read` just generates a key from the value in ~/.lotus/token, so the real question may be how to refresh or update this value...

Answer (score -1):

try to use:

> lotus auth create-token --perm read

I guess you should change your token to use those perms